# Why does there exist a right continuous version of the supermartingale $\{P(L >u \vert F_u),u \geq 0)\}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Why does there exist a right continuous version of the  supermartingale $\{P(L >u \vert F_u),u \geq 0)\}$ where $L$ is a measurable random variable

Its is clear that not all supermartingales have a right continuous versions since the deterministic supermartingale $X=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$ . So these must be something special about this supermartingale but I cant show it. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are there some additional conditions on $L$? For example, $L$ should have no mass points? ($P(L=u)=0$, for any u).

Comment: @Jay.H All we know is that $L$ is a measurable random time taking values in positive reals

Comment: If your filtration is right continuous and complete, you can use the theorem mentioned in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125323/what-conditions-on-a-filtration-guarantee-that-a-submartingale-has-a-continuou

Comment: @Jay.H Thank you . But I think this does not work since we need to prove the existence of a right continuous version and the theorem you are referring to requires that

Comment: No, that theorem only need $E(M_t)$ to be right continuous, which translate to "$P(L>u)$ is right continuous", which in turn, is easy to prove. But you do need some conditions on the filtration.